# when i apply remesh(in sculpting) image texture is not working

Tags: texturing, color, remesh

[image: 1]
you can see in first model I did not apply remesh image texture is woking fine . but in second model I apply remesh and image texture is not working and i am using same texture for both models

Comment: how can i   bake the texture of the original onto the one onto the remeshed version . can you explain little more

Comment: The remesh has changed the UVs, but you could bake the texture of the original onto the remeshed version, just sculpt the way you want then check for a "bake diffuse" tutorial